# DrawerLayout is missing in Android Support Maven repository

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library, drawerlayout

i'm building my projects via maven and would like to use the new DrawerLayout API from Android. As typical this new feature is only available in the Support Library.

Unfortunately the DrawerLayout is missing in the Central Repository (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.android%7Csupport-v4%7Cr7%7Cjar).

Of course i could download the correct jar-file and use this as dependency, but it's not the common way. Is there another way to include the newest version of the Support Library via maven?

Comment: Here is another option, a github repository:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18787121/2776544

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest release of the support library in Maven Central is r7; DrawerLayout was introduced in r13.
One option is to use the jar included with the SDK and [install it to your local maven repo](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). Then you can reference it as a maven dependency.

Comment: Here is how I installed support-v13 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/stephane/programs/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/22.0.0/support-v13-22.0.0.aar -Dpackaging=aar -DgroupId=com.android.support -DartifactId=support-v13 -Dversion=22.0.0 Then I could include the dependency in the pom.xml file:      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v13</artifactId>
      <version>22.0.0</version>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I added the support library v4 **r18** by using **maven-android-sdk-deployer**

https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

Clone the git

```
git clone https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer.git
```

and see the instructions on how to install and configure in README file there.

Just using "mvn install:install-file" didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, here is a github base maven repo that you can use to include v4 r18 of the support tools.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787121/2776544