# A lot of error when create new project in eclipse for Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I installed eclipse and SDK correctly but when I create **new  project**, I get a lot of error.
my R.java file is lost, while there are not file in res that have upper case character
I deleted folders that have error in res folder but created new error

Please help me.
[image]

this picture is my SDK manage if there are a component trhat must be install please say
*Note :* 
**Android SDK Tools 22.6 is installed**
[image]

Comment: You are simply missing a .jar file. Just add it from the sdk folder.

Comment: You need to add the library in `libs` folder in your project: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Comment: you need to add appcompat. For adding appcompact you can check my ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573346/actionbar-in-android-maven-project-using-android-support-library-v7/22573437#22573437

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an error for missing `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` file in your libs folder. I suggest you to add it from your sdk folder's following location

```
sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
```

Comment: What causes this error? How can I get such an error when I have a fresh eclipse installation?

Answer (score 3):

Please Refer this step:

1. From Eclipse (with ADT), select Window > Android SDK Manager.
2. From Android Studio, select Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
3. Start the Android SDK Manager.
4. In the SDK Manager window, scroll to the end of the Packages list, find the Extras
   folder and, if necessary, expand to show its contents.
5. Select the Android Support Library item.

Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install the Android Support
    Repository item instead.

1. Click the Install packages... button.

Check it this process...

Comment: There's no "Android Support Library", there is "Android Support Repository". This is already installed in my eclipse, but I still get lots of errors. Imagine how many people facing such errors just because project managers allow release with high number of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

actually solving this problem is easy:
first you need to find android-support-v7-appcompat.jar and android-support-v4.jar in this folder :

> sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\

(if you can't find them then you should install them from Android SDK Manager: 
Extras/Android Support Library)

and copy them into libs folder in your project inside work-space.

for example:

> \androidWorkspace\projectName\libs

and also make sure in eclipse

> project/properties/Java Build Path

that first two files are connected with those copied files.