# Android.support.v7.appCompat throws NoClassDefFoundError...appcompat.R$styleable

Tags: android, r.java-file

- I'm extends ActionBarActivity at my MainActivity class.
- I use Eclipse to run my project.
- I've add android-support-v7-appcompat.jar at libs folder. then select Build Path for it.
- I manage to see **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar** locate at **Android Private libraries** and **Referenced Libraries**.
- within the gen folder,I manage to see **R.java** under my project **package name**

***I 've refer to [Error implementing Support Library Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851783/error-implementing-support-library-action-bar) .However,my problem still exist.***

one of the comment I notice from the link above

```
Are you completely sure that you have "android.support.v7.appcompat.R.java" in your gen     folder? Without it, it won't work –  Bored
```

My R.java is locate at org.hello.restWebService(my project package name) ,not under android.support.v7.appcompat.Does it because of this?so I get the error.

I'm experience java desktop developer but very **new on android apps development**.So **not very clear about the idea for R.java** and what should its generated contents code looks like .

Hope someone advice,thanks

```
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.hello.rest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-30 23:14:49.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If all you've done is added the jar in your libs directory, then you haven't followed the instructions on how set up the support library.

Comment: no need to put library in lib folder u need to set appcompct from here check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573346/actionbar-in-android-maven-project-using-android-support-library-v7/22573437#22573437