# How to obtain old versions of Android Compatibility libraries

Tags: android, maven

I have a maven Android project which depends on version 21.0.3 of `compatibility-v4` and `compatibility-v7-appcompat`.  I can only see how to use maven-android-sdk-deployer to obtain the latest versions of these libraries (currently 22.0.1), however they are incompatible.

How can I obtain version 21.0.3 of these libraries and use them within a Maven build?

Comment: What is the status of this?

Comment: I still don't know how to use maven-android-sdk-deployer to put these libraries where I need them to be.  Is it the case that it is not possible to use this utility to do that?

Comment: I highly doubt that you can. I would highly suggest you upgrade to Gradle.

Comment: Sadly that's not trivial for my project setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `Gradle` dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3 // current is 22.2.0
}
```

**Some Other previous versions:**

- 22.0.0
- 21.1.1
- 21.1.0
- 21.0.3
- 21.0.0
- 19.1.0
- 19.0.2
- 19.0.1

**You may need to already have versions downloaded but you definitely need to download them through the Android SDK manager:**

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download

**See the support library docs here:**

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

After making sure you have the correct dependencies locally, you can use the Android SDK repo with your project's `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>android-support</id>
        <url>file://${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
    ......
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>19.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602712/950427

Comment: "however they are incompatible" is why I want to do that.  I am using Maven, not Gradle.  Even if I were though, I would need to have it installed via the SDK manager, right?  And I cannot see 21.0.3 available in the SDK manager any more.

Comment: You could never see the "21.0.3". You just download the repository here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download. After specifying the version, you will download it. Once again, you should be using Gradle, either way they are Maven dependencies under the hood.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is really around how to use android-maven-sdk-deployer to achieve this.  Sadly that is too long to use as a SO tag.

Comment: What is incompatible? You can still use my answer setup your `pom.xml` to use your local repo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22602712/950427.

Comment: The app was relying on a class in an `android.support.v7.internal` package which has now moved and changed name.  I'm not sure that is relevant to my question though.  I want to know how I can get Maven to build the app without any code changes.

Comment: Update your code to use the latest libraries so you can maintain it. I have answered your original question.