# gradle build fail Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.1 and ) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.1 and ) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.1

this is  the gradle configuration
what i need to do solve this 
please help me

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.fanbaseafrica.fabaservices'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName '2.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false

            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v4:24.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:24.0.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
    compile 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: please download the library if you dont have it, it must be giving you the download link

Comment: it does give me link to download but it isn't working

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380337/android-support-library-setup-with-maven

Comment: my computer is connected with internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because the support libraries with **24.0.1 don't exist.**

Change with a valid version all your supppor libraries dependencies:

```
24.0.0
24.1.0
24.1.1
24.2.0
```

Here all the [history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

Also some dependencies are wrong:

Change:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v4:24.0.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.X.X'
```

The   `'com.android.support:support-v7:24.X.X'` doesn't exist.

Use

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.x.x'`.

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v4:24.0.0

Comment: Because it is a wrong dependency: use com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0. Just updated the answer.

Comment: I used the ***plus symbol notation*** for any compile lines that were error-ing out `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'`.  Thanks!