# Android Eclipse where is android-support-v7.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I work with Eclipse and Android. I created a new project and I have the following error in a java class

```
import android.support cannot resolved.
```

---

This is my  SDK manager screen

[image]

I installed Android Support Repository.

I want to add android-support-v7.jar to my project. But I don't have folder 
android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\

I have the folder

```
android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support
```

Is the same folder? How can I add android-support-v7.jar to my Eclipse project?

**EDITED**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice to you move to _Android Studio_ because _Google officially ends support for Eclipse Android Developer Tools in favor of Android Studio_

Comment: I do a training and it's mandatory to use Eclipse

Comment: Android studio is better than eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Suspecting you are also using maven as your build tool, add the `m2repository`to your project like:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>android-support</id>
        <url>file://${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
    ......
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>19.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

ref: [Android support library setup with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380337/android-support-library-setup-with-maven)

you have to adjust `env.ANDROID_HOME` and `artifactId`, `version` accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand why when I installed from SDK Manager Android Support Repository I don't have the folder \extras\android\support\v7. I don't want to use Maven.

Comment: The Support Repository *is* the place where SDK-dependencies live.
If you do not use maven, then add the repositores to your top-level build.gradle and the dependecies to the corresponding module (the app).

Comment: I created build.grade. Name's project is Ejemplo2. I edited in my question build.grade. What do I have to do?